# React: Audio does not play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, audio, import

I want an audio to play on a click on a button. The audio has to be choosed based on the selected animal. The function providing the audio looks like this:

```
    function introAudioForAnimal(animal) {
        if (animal == "siri") { return }
        let audioImport = import("../assets/audio/wer_wars/" + animal + "/" + animal + " anfang.wav");
        return new Audio(audioImport);
    }
```

The returned audio is then just played by `introAudioForAnimal("tiger").play();`

The issue is, that nothing plays, but I get an uninformative console error:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at L (index.js:1)
    at Y (index.js:1)
    at index.js:1
    at index.js:1
    at l (index.js:1)
L @ index.js:1
Y @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
l @ index.js:1
game:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

I have already tried logging the exact path:

```
../assets/audio/wer_wars/tiger/tiger anfang.wav
```

This matches my filesystem on where the audio is located.

Any ideas how I can get the audio to play?
If you need any further information, please let me know.

Edit: My browser is google chrome, if that helps you

Comment: add sample https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: I am always getting an error when i try to upload my audiofile on codesandbox

Comment: dont upload,create sample no with music file

Comment: But my problem is based on an audio file.. How should i create a sample?

Comment: Could you please try to remove the the **import** statement as example below?

`let audioImport = "../assets/audio/wer_wars/tiger/tiger anfang.wav"`

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-dan-hjygc?file=/src/index.js:301-514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For everyone else searching, I found a solution:**

First of all I changed the way I defined the path:

```
let audioImport = import(`../assets/audio/wer_wars/${animal}/${animal} anfang.wav`);
```

And the key problem was, that you need to use the default property of that dynamic import to create a new audio:

```
new Audio(audioImport.default);
```

This solution did work for me very well.